# Node with tikz and bookmarks

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, bookmarks

Is it possible to link a bookmark to the command `\titA` in the following example?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
    \newcommand{\titA}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture} \node[circle,shading=ball, ball color=red!80!white, minimum size=1cm]{#1};\end{tikzpicture}}
    \begin{document}
    \titA{blah blah}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the word "bookmark" in this context.  Could you explain what you want to achieve?  Thanks.

Comment: I mean the bookmarks the you usually get in pdf files by using the command \section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the pdf-bookmarks that hyperref provides for chapters and sections can be produced explicitly using the command `\pdfbookmark` from the [hyperref](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/)-package. Maybe like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand{\titA}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture} \node[circle,shading=ball, ball color=red!80!white, minimum size=1cm]{#2\pdfbookmark{#2}{#1}};\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\titA{label}{blah blah}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark/) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\titA}[1]{%
    \bookmark[page=\value{page}]{#1}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node[circle,shading=ball, ball color=red!80!white, minimum size=1cm]{#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\titA{blah blah}

\lipsum

\titA{foo bar}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew this works in my file, do you know if you can also define bookmarks for subsection with this package?

Comment: OK by adding: \usepackage[open, openlevel=2]{bookmark}   \bookmark[level=0, page=\value{page}]{#1} \bookmark[level=1, page=\value{page}]{#1}

Comment: I'd like to get also the view of the beginning of every "section" after clicking on the bookmark and I tried this instruction: view=XYZ 0 100 2, but it doesn't seem to work... Thanks in advance!